# How to keep Realm up-to-date across multiple background services in Android?

Tags: android, service, realm

I'm trying to write data on one service and accessing it from another service.
The data I'm getting from another service is not updated, it's old copy.
Restarting the app sometimes gets updated data.
The services are both normal `Service` extended, so UI thread only.
And I'm not keeping any `realm` instances open anywhere in the app.
How do I ensure it's always new and updated one?

Writing -

`data` is detached using `realm.copyFromRealm(...)`

```
try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    if (realm != null) {
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {
                data.setValue("New value ...");

                realm.insertOrUpdate(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Reading -

```
Data data = null;
try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    if (realm != null) {
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {
                data = realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(Data.class).equalTo("Id", id).findFirst());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Data -

```
public class Data {
    ...
    private String Value;        
    public String getValue() { return Value; }
    public void setValue(String v) { Value = v; }
    ...
}
```

Edit -

I ended up merging both services into one, which works for now. But I'll look forward if anyone can provide some tips or has a similar problem.

Comment: I think "Read"and "Write" is being done in parallel and asynchronously.

You might use the same IntentService for both operations with help of passing different actions to "IntentService"

Comment: @Shivam As per my implementation, they're not parallel. One service asks another service to do write and another service then tells service to do the reading.There is a noticeable time between calls. But I don't know how realm is doing it in its code.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I ensure it's always new and updated one?

Don't use `copyFromRealm()`. and use `RealmResults` field variable + `RealmChangeListener`

```
 RealmResults<T> results;
 RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> listener = new RealmChangeListener<...>() {
    @Override public void onChange(RealmResults<T> results) {
         ...
    }
 }


 public void something() {
    results = realm.where(...).findAll*();
    results.addChangeListener(
```